# Reference directories correctly when launching a .jar from a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, path, directory

How to reference directories correctly when launching a .jar from a batch file?

I am trying to launch a jar file from a .bat . One of the first things my code does is open and read from a file. I reference the file like this:

```
final ArrayList<EmailAccount> emailList = FileIO.getListOfAccountsFromFile(".\\EmailList\\list.txt");
```

Everything works fine if the batch file is in the same directory as my jar. HOWEVER, if I put my batch file somewhere else and try to run it (like i plan to have it work), the program thinks that I'm trying to reference a file that is in the

```
".bat directory"\EmailList\list.txt
```

instead of

```
".jar directory"\EmailList\list.txt
```

and comes up with a fileNotFoundException.

Is there any way that I can run my batch file from a different directory while correctly referencing files in relation to the jar without hard coding in the jar's file path?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Thank you, I was able to modify that code to make it usable in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask the JVM about the location of a given class.  If you *know* it is inside the jar  you refer to, then you can then extract the location of the jar file, and then construct your file objects relative to that.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/320595/53897 for details about

```
return new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```